# Node.js Redis library is not adding any key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, geolocation, geospatial

I want to store real-time location information in Redis with node.js, but my code isn't adding anything to the Redis database.

In my code below, whenever a request is made to the middleware that updates the location I'm trying to first list out the current Redis keys, then I try and add/update the information sent to the server. When I log the current list an empty array is returned, and when I do `console.log(location)` inside the `.then` block 0 is logged. However, when I log the `location` variable I get

```
{
  member: '1',
  latitude: 'latitude',
  longitude: 'longitude'
}
```

What could be some reasons why nothing is being added to the Redis database? My code is below:

```
storeNewLocation: (req, res) => {
    const location = {
        member: req.body.id.toString(),
        latitude: req.body.lng.toString(),
        longitude: req.body.lat.toString(),
    };
    console.log(location);

    redis
        .geoRadiusWith(
            "users",
            {
                latitude: "latitude",
                longitude: "longitude",
            },
            50,
            "mi",
        )
        .then((usersList) => {
            console.log(usersList);
        });

    redis
        .geoAdd("users", location)
        .then((location) => {
            console.log(location);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing `lat`, `lon` values anywhere. They are just `'latitude'` and `'longitude'` strings. These are invalid lat and lon values for redis to save. Please check the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd/).

> - Valid longitudes are from -180 to 180 degrees.
> - Valid latitudes are from -85.05112878 to 85.05112878 degrees.